# Auto Increment the number

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql

I have a problem regarding create squence of number, but i face some problem like given below. I want a number Format Like UK 0000, there are some conditon applied:

1. It start from UK 0001
2. After reaches 9 record then 10th record is like UK 0010
3. If all digit fill Like UK 9999 then next record show like UK 10000 and so on

Please help me for this, It can use any platform like

- jquery
- c#
- sql etc...

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: *"It can use any platform like jquery,c#,sql"* These are totally different languages and platforms, you need to to be specific!

Comment: You could use a macro in excel i guess... Be aware, SO is not please-code-it.com

Comment: As other have already mentioned: http://whathaveyoutried.com? Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in c#, you can do this

```
string s = "UK";
int counter = 0;
if (counter < 10000)
   result = s + counter++.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
else
   result = s + counter++.ToString();
```

**Output:** UK0000,UK0001,UK0002......

Answer (score 1):

```
  IEnumerable<int> numbers= Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(x=>x);
  var list = squares.Select(numbers => "UK" + numbers.ToString("0000")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
List<string> lista = new List<string>();
for (int num = 0; num < 12000; num++)
{
    lista.Add(string.Format("UK {0}", num > 999 ? num.ToString() : num.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**USING JQUERY -** Here is a working example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/wwytf/4/)

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var prefix = "UK";
    var max = 4;
    var limit = 10004;
    for (var i = 0; i < limit - 1; i++) {
        var a = prefix + pad(i, max);
        $("#msg").append(a);
        $("#msg").append("<br/>");
    }

    function pad(str, max) {
        str = str.toString();
        return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
    }
});
```